# How to read oslo config value in unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I have some Japaneses character in my `nova.conf` file.

`クラ`

After reading from config file I have to decode it in `utf-8` like

```
my_data = CONF.test.test
my_data = my_data.decode('utf-8')
```

When I use variable without decode, its giving `UnicodeDecodeError`

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there any way to read data from config directly in decoded form?

Comment: I think you need to _encode_ it. `my_data.encode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to read data from config directly in decoded form?

not in python 2.7. Because in python prior to python 3, strings default to ASCII strings, whereas in python 3 strings default to unicode strings. So basically:

```
>>> mydata = "クラ"
>>> print mydata.decode('utf-8')
クラ
>>> print mydata
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

whereas in python 3:

```
>>> mydata = "クラ"
>>> print(mydata)
クラ
```

So if you want to handle unicode strings painlessly, it's time for you to do the switch.